# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_8_6_2

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to get response from Elasticsearch. However when we have hits I am getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_8_6_2

How to handle this?

The method is as below

```java
public static string elsasticconnect(String indexname,String query)
{
     CredentialsProvider Provider1 = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
     Provider1.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxx", "yyyy"));

     RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("xxxx", 9200, "http")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder ->                          httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(csProvider1)));
           
     QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query);
     SearchSourceBuilder Builder1 = new SearchSourceBuilder();
     Builder1.query(qb);
     SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexname);
     searchRequest.source(Builder1);
     SearchResponse scrollResp1 = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
     System.out.println(scrollResp1);
     return scrollResp1.toString();
}
```

I am getting error when there is documents returning from Elasticsearch. How to handle this?

Comment: Most likely, your client library version is not in line with your ES server version.

Comment: Elasticsearch has lucene version 9.4.2 also added the same dependency in the pom.xml, but giving same error but different version now LUCENE_7_0_0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_7_0_0

Comment: I'm talking about the Elasticsearch versions, client and server

Comment: Errors like this generally indicate you have incompatible versions of dependencies on your classpath.